# Why did my reputation fall down to 1?

Tags: support, reputation, spam

Suddenly my Stack Overflow reputation went down to 1 from 379, and I cannot see the reason for this from my reputation page, I mean there's no -378 entry. But when I click [this](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2011-03-01/106303#106303) link, I can see that my reputation is still 379. What's the explanation of this? Or is this some kind of an early April Fool's Day activity?

Comment: That looks weird indeed. It's normal behaviour if an account gets suspended but that's not the case in your case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>May be recalc your reps at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation</s>

Many of your answers have been flagged as spam.

> [Where are the best explanations of memory management for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710288/where-are-the-best-explanations-of-memory-management-for-iphone/5492982#5492982)
>
> [Learn Obj-C Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370427/learn-obj-c-memory-management/5493021#5493021)
>
> [Memory Management in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106627/memory-management-in-objective-c/5493023#5493023)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246138/what-is-the-best-url-or-book-about-memory-management-in-objective-c/5492831#5492831
>
> [Objective-C/iOS : Message sent to deallocated instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486888/objective-c-ios-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance/5488937#5488937)

-100 for each, so you reps is now 1

I am not sure those are spam, and I didn't flagged it as such, IIRC.