# Reposting an identical answer on a different question

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, reposts

What is the policy for the following scenario?

I just saw the following answer posted: [utf8_unicode_ci vs utf8_general_ci collation differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987572/utf8-unicode-ci-vs-utf8-general-ci-collation-differences/5500391#5500391)

This is a good answer to the question: it details exactly what the differences that the OP wanted to know, clearly and in detail. Ordinarily, I would expect it to score highly.

However, I notice that the question is several months old and already has an accepted answer. Plus, although the accepted answer doesn't give the same detail, it does include a link to a site that does.

So I got a bit curious... and a quick trip to Google revealed that in fact, the user who posted this new answer had already posted the identical answer some time ago on another question: [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci/766996#766996)

It is identical: exact copy and paste. But it's also by the same author, so I guess it doesn't break any plaguarism rules on that score. But it still feels like it's just a slightly cynical grab for points (and possibly also for a Necromancer badge).

Comment: Surely if the same answer applies to both questions then the questions are duplicates....

Comment: I asked for the same flagging an answer as "other" once, and got an "It's OK" response from a mod.

Answer (score 7):

Answering old questions (if with relevant info) is perfectly fine.  Same goes for answering questions with already accepted answers; you might even steal the accept.

And, since [we've stopped worrying and now love dupes,](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) it is more than possible to find similar questions where you can use the exact same answer.

So, with only the slightest reservation ([your wingwang may get slammed in the doorjam by the spam detector algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85439/why-did-my-reputation-fall-down-to-1)) I'd say go for it.

Comment: This contradicts this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/286330

Comment: @n1000 check the dates, consider the content of each, decide for yourself.