# Should multiple duplicate answers by a single user be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User posting exact duplicate answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113385/user-posting-exact-duplicate-answers-to-multiple-questions)

I saw a user post the exact same answer over and over again:

1. [Java object copy best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144673/java-object-copy-best-option/9835859#9835859)
2. [Java: pass in copy of “this”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481952/java-pass-in-copy-of-this/9835714#9835714)
3. [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java/9834683#9834683)
4. [how to deep copy object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479989/how-to-deep-copy-object-in-java/9835936#9835936)
5. [Java :deep copy, shallow copy, clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182565/java-deep-copy-shallow-copy-clone/9835954#9835954)

Should this be flagged as a duplicate answer, or is this ok?

Comment: If it's an *exact* duplicate (word for word, which it is in this case) then the system has already flagged us.  It's not bad if you do it, but chances are we already know.  However, if one or two things are changed, then chances are we don't know.  Feel free to flag us regardless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the answers are exact duplicates, they are automatically flagged. What you can do is verify if any of the questions are duplicates, and flag/vote to close them.

Generally speaking, a duplicate answer could mean the questions are duplicates. Voting to close (or flagging, if you don't have the reputation to vote to close) helps the moderators more than flagging duplicated answer, especially in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Answer are word to word same automatically flagged and 10k + user can see

> [image]

but in such case if answer are slightly different in wording ... but yet duplicate feel free to flag.