# Cross-posting the same answer to multiple questions about the same topic

Tags: discussion, answers, cross-posting

I found at least 5 different questions about my problem here in StackOverflow; unfortunately none of the answers helped me fix the issue, and then I stumbled upon the solution quite by chance.

Now my question: Is it valid to cross-post the solution in all those other questions I found, just so others find it more easily?

Comment: We like to at least *pretend* that we don't keep repeating ourselves in our answers, even though invariably we do.

Answer (score 9):

Before you do this, ask yourself the questions:

- How many of those questions should be marked as duplicates? Or can some of them be merged?
- Will your answer be identical for all the questions, or can you tailor it to each question?

I would advise against posting the exact same answer to all the questions, as that isn't really helpful and is behavior usually seen from people on a [reputation fishing expedition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113431/146015).

Comment: Got it ;-) Upon closer inspection, actually just two out of those five questions have a description that fits my initial problematic and I think those two _could_ be merged.

Comment: I ran into a situation where two questions that ask the same thing were both protected by the community - thus not being allowed to be flagged as a duplicate. Also because I answered both of them with the same answer one of my answers got deleted by a moderator. I do not think that is fair. How do we deal with this?

Comment: @Radmation you should include links to the questions - without seeing them I can't comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover. @slugster Do you think there should be questions specific to the version of bootstrap?

Comment: @Radmation the problem is probably your lack of rep - I just voted to close as dupe on one of them not a problem (without unprotecting it). As for version specific questions - yes, why not? When tagging they should have the generic tag, with the version tag added if it matters.