# Does copying of my own text (with minor edits) from Stack Exchange come under purview of plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I have a mathematical proof of my own for my research article which I wanted to share with Stack Exchange to get a confirmation of how correct my proof is. But, I am scared of plagiarism when communicating for communication. So,

**Does copying of my own text (with minor edits) from Stack Exchange for my research articles come under purview of plagiarism?**

Comment: For the plagiarism part, you can read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333708/is-it-acceptable-to-copy-your-own-answer-verbatim-from-an-off-site-resource).  That part will probably be okay.  The sticky part is if any site accepts confirmation of proofs.

Comment: No, wait, I read that wrong. It's the opposite scenario, are you allowed to use your own SE content in your off-SE research. I've retracted my dupe-close vote, but I do think it's off-topic for meta as it deals with "regular" policies, not Stack Exchange ones. I can't vote to close again because of the retracted vote, though.

Comment: Would this not be better on the Academia SE or even on one of the maths ones as custom and practice may differ by discipline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Does copying of my own text(with minor edits) from Stack Exchange for my research articles come under purview of plagiarism?**

I don't think so. *Plagiarizing* is defined as using other peoples work without clear citing, as it would be your own.

Though adding a link to the original source at Stack Exchange, would be good.

Comment: But, i have no idea as how to cite Stack Exchange in my reasearch article?

Comment: @gete Are you talking about copying an **old** answer of yours from SO, Maths etc. to a **new** answer within the same network?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A No. I am talking about copying my answer in  SO, Maths etc to a scientific research article for pulications in journals.

Comment: @gete then you have to ask your professors or tutor. Visit Academia SE, and see if anyone else before you asked the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Contributions to the site are covered by the Creative Commons licence https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/ which requires attribution of material taken from the site and various other things. It is not specific about what happens if it is your own material and I am not a lawyer but it would seem safest to provide a link to the relevant page where your question is in the reference section of your article. The journal will have specific instructions about how to cite a web page, the ones I see usually have the link and then text about when it was consulted but your field may vary. The editor can advise you about where in the article to call out the citation.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is, you are posting on SE for review and possible alternation of your work. You may make some minor changes recommended by others to the original work, you may get more ideas about the proof, and SE is publicly searchable.
Therefore it's a good idea to [cite SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/citing-stackexchange-postings)

Technically, using others and your own prior work without giving credits is plagiarism. Although I don't see it would be a huge problem to use you own work, what is stopping you from spending the little time to properly cite it if you are scared of having communication of plagiarism?