# Is it acceptable to copy my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks, duplicate-answers

Is it generally accepted to copy my own answers across questions / exchange sites?
(assuming the questions are not duplicates and the answer solves both questions)

Should I link back to the original?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Is it acceptable to copy your own answer verbatim from an off-site resource?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333708/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Good find, thanks! Even more appropriately, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298464/do-we-have-a-policy-about-self-plagiarism), which is linked there. I'm voting to close this one as duplicate (but not deleting, since it's useful for search)

Comment: Don't copy your answers! If your answer turns out to be wrong or eventually becomes outdated, someone will have to edit all those copies.