# Answering similar questions when they are not exact duplicates

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, android

This is the first time I'm dealing with a situation like this, so I'm seeking some guidance. I've read several related questions on meta, including ["What's the etiquette for answering two similar questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137330/whats-the-etiquette-for-answering-two-similar-questions) and ["Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions), which clarified things up a bit, but I'm still unsure.

Here's the story: two days ago I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190949/is-it-posible-to-have-separatedlistadapter-inside-expandablelistadapter/). The user was asking if it is possible to put a custom view into an expandablelistview. I looked at the source code of the custom view the user was referring to and figured out that his custom view was derived from ListView, and Android does not allow one scrollable view inside another scrollable view. So the answer basically consists of two points: 1: Your custom view is inherited from a ListView. 2: You can't put a ListView into another scrollable view.

And then today there is another [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234349/can-listview-be-inside-expandablelistview/), only this time a different user is trying to put a ListView directly into an ExpandableListView, without the custom view part, and the correct answer should just consist of point 2 from the previous paragraph.

What should I do with se second question, mark as duplicate? But the second question is not really an exact duplicate, it's rather a half of the first question. What's the right approach here?

Comment: Perhaps add a comment to look at the other question, detailing the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an exact duplicate, you can mark it as duplicate and vote to close it. Only if the duplicate question doesn't answer the question completely, you need to post an answer. In this case, you could have marked it as duplicate and closed it since your other answer completely answers this second question as well.

If you feel that there is a considerable difference between both questions, try to include those extra details to this answer so that it doesn't look like an exact copy of other one. As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104292/200687), just copying and pasting the same exact answer is not acceptable.