# I lost all reputation on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

In the morning [I had 277 reputation with 12 badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453767/articlestack?tab=stats). I answered some questions and came to my office. Here I see -276 reputation. But in the history there is no reason/activity of this. It has happened with me previously as well but for 5 - 10 reputation only.

What happened to my reputation?

Yesterday it was showing 18 answers, then only 15 answers in the evening. Today it is showing 10 answers. How can I find those missing answers?

Comment: might be this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85439/why-did-my-reputation-fall-down-to-1

Comment: Looking at your [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/453767/articlestack), do you notice that any of your answers are missing? You have 15 now; did you have more before?

Comment: This looks strange - I can confirm that this user had some 277 reputation just a few hours ago. The rep graph isn't showing anything either

Comment: as per @Henrik's comment, I'd check out that linked post, you [recently replied to an old post with a link to your own site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521198/how-to-add-indian-rupee-symbol-in-prestashop/6039582#6039582), a lot of people see that as spam and it was probably flagged (were there others which were actually deleted?), though reading the other post comments - if you think something is still not well try emailing `team@stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @articlestack, I just saw, there are again two of your questions with 3 flags in the flag queue, please revisit your contribution, and read the FAQ.

Comment: How can i check it? I think people have decided to follow my all answers and dying to flag them :(

Comment: @articlestack: I seriously doubt anyone is following your answers just to flag them. People come across one of them when browsing questions, and notice that it looks similar to all the rest of your answers. You're not the only one this happens to... Users who post virtually identical answers to multiple questions have their posts flagged as spam *all the time*. The community has a pretty low tolerance for this. If you can copy and paste the exact same answer to another question, and it actually answers the question, you'd be better off flagging the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to provide some additional, *targeted* information. How does the link you posted solve their problem? What does the code/whatever actually *do*? Elaboration is key. A good answer doesn't require that you follow a link at all. All the information is embedded in the body of the answer itself. This is the way I write mine: even if I link to an external resource, it is for supplemental reasons only, not the main body of my answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray, had this same thing happen to me. If answers are flagged for any reason, isnit an act of transparency that the user is notified and the person flagging is identified as well to avoid mischief?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have placed a bounty on a question or just performed a reputation recalc, then the most likely explanation is that you had a couple of your answers deleted after 6 different users flagged them as being "spam" or "offensive".

Each answer deletion [costs you -100 rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175), an easy explanation for your overnight decrease.

Another possibility is that the system detected some suspicious voting patterns coming from your account, causing it to perform an automatic reputation recalculation. That can negatively affect your reputation if some of the questions you've answered have been migrated to other sites or deleted altogether.

Comment: This is true. There are three answers of this user deleted as spam.

Comment: They where in the flag list. Link to one of them (10k only): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126280/rupee-symbol-in-mail/6039590#6039590

Comment: @Gamecat: I meant, how did you find the deleted post in the first place? Non-moderators can't see deleted answers in the user profile. You can only get to them if you have a link. How'd you get the link? You just happen to remember them being in the flag list?

Comment: You can see the post if you have flagged for them. (Click on the flag weight in your profile).

Answer (score 10):

To add the extra information.

You had three answers with similar text and a link that where flagged as spam and deleted.

If you don't want your answers to be flagged, provide some more information with the link. But three posts with the same answer are extremely suspicious.

Links for 10k users visible.

1. [Rupee symbol in mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126280/rupee-symbol-in-mail/6039590#6039590)
2. [HTML code for INR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430242/html-code-for-inr/6039600#6039600)
3. [Displaying the Indian currency symbol on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/how-to-add-indian-currency-symbol-in-your-website/6039608#6039608)

Comment: 1. I m not able to provide additional information since they are locked. 2. It should be refelected in graph

Comment: @articlestack - By providing additional information, what is meant is that in the future, don't just post links back to your website as answers.  These will be flagged as spam and deleted.  Write a full answer, and only link back to your site when you want to provide supplemental information that users may wish to read in addition to your answer.

Comment: I thought i had provided enough information. Although i'll care from next time